# Why did my laptop refuse to start?

Tags: boot, cpu, upgrade, processor-socket

I tried to upgrade my processor. The chip inside is:

**Intel Pentium Dual Core T4200**,

and I used this chip:

**Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor P8800 3M Cache, 2.66 GHz, 1066 MHz FSB (SocketP)**

http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/CPUs/Intel/Core_2_Duo_Mobile/P8800_(SocketP).html

However, my laptop then refused to boot, it only turned on for a few seconds.
Luckily, it booted back up with my old chip.

Questions:

1. Why did this happen?
2. And what is the maximum upgrade that I can use for my 
   **Dell Inspiron 1545 PP41L** laptop?

edit:
According to this site, P8800 is TOO, the maximum possible upgrade.

http://www.benshardwareblog.com/laptop-hardware/upgrading-a-dell-inspiron-1545-cpu?_ga=2.258778634.1604821919.1549533801-1946782133.1549533801

The laptop now boots in about 26 seconds. That is, from switch on,  until I hear the **Windows welcome sound**.....

Comment: Since it's so incredibly easy to replace the cpu, I did it, but **WITHOUT** applying the termal paste, also because I don't have any here. Could that be it?

Comment: Try again with thermal paste.  Likely just overheated and turned itself off.

Comment: Are there any good manuals on how to apply the thermal paste??

Comment: Okay, so simple youtubing gave me several vids of how to apply thermal paste, and i went with the "P" or "pea"-method, and not the spread-out-with-creditcard-method, nor the line, nor the "X" method, because they were all the same in temparature. Amazingly, it worked! So, I've upgraded this 10 yr old laptop for about  € 50,-: a WD Green 240gb SSD (230 HK dollars) and a P8800 chip (70 HK$) . I got 4gb memory for 35 HK$ in a repair shop in that humongous pc/gaming/laptop shopping mall they have. Laptop belonged to an old lady who used it only for email. On Sundays ;)

Answer (score -1):

### Good news:

Your new chip is indeed compatible with your laptop.
However, the P8800 includes the SSE4.1 instruction set which is only supported starting with BIOS version A13 of Nov. 2009.

The newest BIOS version, A14 can be found [on the official Dell Website](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/drivers/driversdetails?driverId=NDG06&osCode=WLH&productCode=inspiron-1545)

### Bad news:

As you have added in a comment that you ran the new CPU without thermal compound, this may have killed the chip. It certainly does explain the laptop not booting at all. CPUs without thermal compound can barely transmit the heat of running to the heatsink and as a result run hot almost instantaneously. The BIOS then halts all further booting.

Depending on how Long you ran the laptop like this, it may have broken the chip.

Comment: Sadly, my Bios is already A14, so that can not be the cause.

Comment: Do you have a way of making sure the processor isn't faulty? The CPU definitely is compatible. Sometimes even a simple re-seat of the processor does the trick.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion of how I could make sure of that?

Comment: You might want to research the BIOS reset procedure, and after installing the new CPU use the procedure.  No guarantee it will work.

Comment: Not gonna fly, I dont'even see the BIOS when the new cpu is in. I will get some thermal paste tomorrow, see if that helps.

Comment: Running a CPU without thermal compound, even for a short period of time can damage the chip significantly. If the CPU even works anymore, you might run into problems with stability and shortened lifespan along the way.